# How to generate a dataframe column to keep track of a file version

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, version

I have a dataframe that stores the dates of creation and upgrades of files. I would like to write a function in order to create a column named 'version' keeping track of the files versions.

original dataset:

```
| fileID | creationDate         | upgradeDate          |
|--------|----------------------|----------------------|
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 |
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 02/02/2022  15:30:00 |
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 10/02/2022  10:00:00 |
| file_2 | 03/02/2022  15:00:00 | 03/02/2022  15:00:00 |
| file_3 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 |
| file_3 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 | 05/02/2022  15:00:00 |
```

what I would like:

```
| fileID | creationDate         | upgradeDate          | version |
|--------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 1       |
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 02/02/2022  15:30:00 | 2       |
| file_1 | 02/02/2022  15:00:00 | 10/02/2022  10:00:00 | 3       |
| file_2 | 03/02/2022  15:00:00 | 03/02/2022  15:00:00 | 1       |
| file_3 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 | 1       |
| file_3 | 04/02/2022  15:00:00 | 05/02/2022  15:00:00 | 2       |
```

I was able to do this through a for loop :

```
ids = df['fileID'].unique().tolist()
for id in ids:
    df.loc[df['fileID'] == id, 'version'] = range(1, len(df.loc[df['fileID'] == id]) + 1)
```

But I would prefer not to use a for loop and do it with a function or list comprehension. Any idea ?

Comment: Try `df["version"] = df.groupby("fileID").cumcount() + 1`

Comment: I'll add to @Timus 's response...

`df['date_aware_version_calculation'] = df.sort_values('upgradeDate').groupby('fileID').cumcount()`

Comment: didn't know this function ! Thanks it helps a lot